# Angularjs TreeView Directive With Isolated Scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create treeview directive with isolated scope.

But node selection not working properly:

**Directive**

```
(function(l) {
    l.module("angularTreeview", []).directive("treeModel",
        function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    treeModel: '=',
                    currentNode: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    k = '<ul><li data-ng-repeat="node in treeModel"><i class="collapsed" data-ng-show="node.children.length && node.collapsed" data-ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i><i class="expanded" data-ng-show="node.children.length && !node.collapsed" data-ng-click="selectNodeHead(node)"></i><i class="normal" data-ng-hide="node.children.length"></i> <span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node)">{{node.roleName}}</span><div data-ng-hide="node.collapsed" data-tree-model="node.children" data-node-id="roleId" data-node-label="roleName" data-current-node="currentNode" data-node-children="children"></div></li></ul>';

                    scope.$watch('treeModel', function() {
                            element.empty().html($compile(k)(scope))
                        }),
                        scope.selectNodeLabel = function(q) {
                            scope.currentNode && scope.currentNode.selected && (scope.currentNode.selected = false);
                            q.selected = "selected";
                            scope.currentNode = q
                        };
                }
            }
        })
})(angular);
```

[**Problem Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLafesnx/)

Any help would appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because you compile the directive multiple times, you have different child scopes for each time you compile the directive. Now it's not a real problem but every child node change to `currentNode` changes the reference but does not update all of its parents scopes, meaning the original currentNode is not updated.

Instead you can access the currentNode through an object which will guarantee that every change will keep the referencs as they are:

```
// controller
$scope.obj = { currentNode :{} };

// directive
scope.currentNode.currentNode=q; // every line with scope.currenNode becomes scope.currentNode.currentNode for example.
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xczk2qh/)